Meta-analysis of odds ratio for continuous variables, how to interpret the decrease or increase per unit?
So, I am doing a meta-analysis of odds ratios to find out the risk factors for a certain medical outcome. One of those risk factors would be (simplified) the time spent in the operation room. My problem is that I have certain studies that use 1 min increments, others 10 min and others 1 hour. As I understand it, I can only pool those results if the relation is linear, but how can I find out if it is?
And also, how can I then interpret the result? Can I really say that with every supplementary hour the odds increase by so and so ? Or is it compared to the median time, that if you add 1 hour to that, the odds increase? Because I have to assume it reaches a plateau at some point, don't I?
I hope my question is somewhat clear. Sorry for my english.

If $\exp{(\beta)}$ is the odds ratio for an increase of 1 unit, $\exp{(z\beta)}$ is the odds ratio for an increase of $z$ units. So just transform the reported odds ratios to the same unit. But also see this post.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
